# How do I create a valid JSON object to use with jsTree?

Tags: jstree

It seems that nothing I do works. I need to create a JSON object before I create the jsTree and NOTHING works. I've gotten as far as:

var jsonObj = {};
jsonObj.data = "Node1";

$('#treeView').jstree({
 "json_data" : jsonObj
});

This works great if I only want one node, but how do I implement jsonObj to have multiple nodes with children?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/radek/4fTDq/

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 
    "data" : "node_title",
    "children" : [ /* an array of child nodes objects */ ]
}
```

[jstree documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data)